# Как вызвать работу одного класса в другом? c#

Tags: c#, xnet

Мне нужно, чтобы после класса Programm(привязка HWID), выполнялся класс check(сама программа). (Всё это консольные приложения)

```
class Programm
{
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
КОД
}
```

```
class check
{
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
КОД
}
```

Comment: `Main` может быть в приложении только один, а `Program` пишется с одной буквой `m`. Начните с изучения азов, разберитесь что такое объекты и классы. Например [вот учебник](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/).

Comment: Это всё понятно, что он может быть один... Как мне в итоге вызвать работу второго класса, в первом?

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_

Comment: `Как мне в итоге вызвать работу второго класса, в первом?` я же вам написал как и ссылку дал. Вам нужно узнать, что такое объекты и классы, там же и узнаете ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Уточните вопрос: вы хотите использовать из одной **программы** вторую **программу**, или из одного **класса** второй **класс**?

Comment: Получается, что из одной **программы** вторую **программу**. **Program.cs** - отвечает за HWID привязку, а **check.cs** - уже за программу.

Comment: То, что класс1 отвечает за ответственность1, а класс2 отвечает за ответственность2 -- не говорит о том, что это обязаны быть программы. В проекте как раз стараются приходить к тому, что у каждого класса одна ответственность, а Program.Main делают один. И не стоит весь код загонять в статические методы -- зачем вам тогда вообще классы, чисто для группировки кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить консольное приложение, в котором есть две точки входа. Вы можете использовать методы из класс check таким образом:

```
using System;

namespace ClassUseClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static check c = new check();
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Это метод из класса Program");
            c.Main2();
        }
    }
    class check
    {
        public void Main2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Это метод из класса check");
        }
    }
}
```

Иначе класс check будет хранилищем для методов.